# How to disable MCE Remote in Ubuntu?

Tags: xbmc, remote-control

I have an HTPC (running XBMCBuntu) and a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 and I recently purchased an MCE Remote for my HTPC which works great using `lirc`. I just noticed the remote is also controlling my laptop! I've been searching high and low trying to find out how to get this to stop but have had no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo rmmod ite_cir` should fix the issue.

You can also create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-mceusb.conf` and add

```
#Blacklist mce usb
blacklist ite_cir
```

to the file. Then restart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if lirc was configured on your laptop by the installer. Sounds far fetched but...if so you should be able to disable it.

Comment: i checked for that. lirc is not installed on my laptop.